# React-Native-AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

> I am using async storage to store the values, but while retrieving it is overriding the values which i saved previous it is not showing. 
>   while getting data only latest record is showing.
>   i have some buttons in flat list on every click i am storing data in an array, and i want to retrieve all data but it shows only latest record.

First.js -save data

```js
saveData= async (item)=>{
console.log("We are in SAve function")

try{
var product= [];
var items={
    id: item.id,
    title: item.title,
    image: item.image,
    price: item.price,
    description:item.description,
    categoryTitle: item.categoryTitle,
  }

  AsyncStorage.getItem("Cart",(err,res)=>{
    if(!res){
      alert("empty cart")
      AsyncStorage.setItem("Cart",JSON.stringify([product]))
    }
    else{

     product.push(items);

      AsyncStorage.setItem("Cart",JSON.stringify(product),
      console.log("item added" +JSON.stringify(product)));
      alert("item added to cart")
    }
  })
}
catch(error)
{
    alert(eror)
}

}
```

Getting data-

```js
 componentWillMount(){
  AsyncStorage.getItem("Cart",(err,res)=>{
      console.log("res value is------" +JSON.stringify(res))
      if(!res)
      {
          alert("your cart is empty")
      }
      else{

        this.setState({cartItems:JSON.parse(res)},
         console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.cartItems))),

        alert(JSON.stringify("get Cart items"+JSON.stringify(this.state.cartItems)));

      }
  });
```

}

```js
 _renderItem({item}){
  console.log("we are in _renderItem function"  )

     console.log(item.id)


        return  this.state.cartItems.map((item,id) =>{


            return(
            <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>

             <Image style={{height:90,width:90}} source= {{uri: item.image}} />
            <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}> 
             <Text>  {item.id} </Text>   
             <Text>  {item.title} </Text>  
              <Text> {item.categoryTitle} </Text>  


            </View>

             </View>
            );
        });

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

After using async and await my cart is empty showing as i am getting the length of array according to that it is showing empty.
this is the render function:-

```js
<View>

           {this.state.cartItems.length<=0 ?

            <View style={{justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>

                <Text> cart is empty</Text>

            </View>    

             :


             <View>

             <FlatList
             extraData={this.state}
              data={this.state.cartItems}
              renderItem={this._renderItem}

              keyExtractor={(item,index)=> item}


             />

         </View>
```

After using async and await:-

```js
componentWillMount= async ()=>{
 const value= await AsyncStorage.getItem("Cart",(err,res)=>{
      console.log("res value is------" +JSON.stringify(res))
      if(value==null)
      {
          alert("your cart is empty")
      }
      else{

        this.setState({cartItems:JSON.parse(res)},
         console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.cartItems))),

        alert(JSON.stringify("get Cart items"+JSON.stringify(this.state.cartItems)));

      }
  });
```

}

here I want list of data which is user adding :-

```js
 _renderItem=({item})=>{
  console.log("we are in _renderItem function"  )

     console.log(item.id)



      return(


        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>

        <Image style={{height:90,width:90}} source= {{uri: item.image}} />

       <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}> 
        <Text>  {item.id} </Text>   
        <Text>  {item.title} </Text>  
         <Text> {item.categoryTitle} </Text>  


       </View>

        </View>
      )




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Sava data items:-

```js
 saveData (item){
console.log("We are in SAve function")

try{
var product= [];

var items={
    id: item.id,
    title: item.title,
    image: item.image,
    price: item.price,
    description:item.description,
    categoryTitle: item.categoryTitle,
  }

     AsyncStorage.getItem("Cart",(err,res)=>{
     if(!res){
     alert("empty cart")
     AsyncStorage.setItem("Cart",JSON.stringify([product]))
     }
     else{

     product.push(items);          
     AsyncStorage.setItem("Cart",JSON.stringify(product),
     console.log("item added" +JSON.stringify(product)));
     alert("item added to cart")
     console.log(product);

  }
  })
}
catch(error)
{
    alert(eror)
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `async` and `await` while retrieving data from asyncstorage.

read more : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Comment: I added async and await but now my cart is empty showing i updated my code please check it.

Comment: @NishantMathur try putting getItem into one const without any function in like you are currently doing
your const will be filled with return value when you getitem from your asyncstorage, check if the value is null below and after asyncstorage get item

Comment: sir actually single data is coming only but not rendering previous saved items,m can you please give me an example or code

Comment: Sir as you said i did the same value is coming in string, and i compare with null data is coming but sir i also want to render in list please tell me how i can do that ?  Thanks in advance

Comment: put the return value into state and the list you want to render in have a datasource of that state, with react native when you update the state, the list will automatically re-render.

i will try to make a mock example for you @NishantMathur

Comment: this is my saving state of each item i am pushing items into an array, like we add an item in cart so while retrieving it shows single item only because every time item is inserting in array on console but not retrieving. I m uploading my code of saving state.